# Strange behavior of blockproc when adding border pixels to the block

Tags: image, matlab, block

I'm having a hard time understanding what is going on when I use this parameter of the `blockproc` function:

When I try a simple function

```
fun = @(block) mean(mean(block.data));
im4 = blockproc(im1,[BlockSize BlockSize],fun);
```

It works like a charm. 
Now the same function but when blocks include border pixels:

```
fun = @(block) mean(mean(block.data));
im4 = blockproc(im1,[BlockSize BlockSize],fun, 'BorderSize', [BlockSize BlockSize]);
```

It returns an empty im4. No error message, just an empty value. Changing the `'TrimBorder'` or `'PadPartialBlock'` parameters did not do any change. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: what is the `blocksize` and the size of `im1`? I am guessing they are multiples of each other.

Comment: @Parag `blocksize` is 9, the image is of size 800x800, so not a multiple. Should it be a multiple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function has a very simple logic. If a border of 2 pixels was added, it will remove two pixels after processing the block. Your function outputs a scalar, after removing the border an empty array remains.

You have to turn trimborder off:

```
im4 = blockproc(im1,[BlockSize BlockSize],fun,'BorderSize', [1 1],'TrimBorder',false);
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't understand the 'TrimBorder' that way. That is embarrassing... Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think it would be nice to have a warning or error telling the user that the border trim is taking out all the output data.

Comment: @Jigg: Probably no one hat the idea to put in such strange inputs ^^